# Which Method is better to display large result from database?

Tags: mysql

Few days back, I posted a question about getting student marks results from database with least number of queries.
What I need to know is which of the following approach is better?

Case A

1. Query all students from the database
2. Then for **EACH** student, Query the result from the database
3. This way, if we have 100 students, we need to query the database 100 times.
4. Example:

   ```
   $Students = mysql_query(SELECT student_id, student_name FROM STUDENTS WHERE class_id = 2);

   while($student = mysql_fetch_assoc($Students) {
       $Result = mysql_query("SELECT marks FROM result WHERE student_id = ".$student['student_id']);
       // Process result

   }
   ```

Case B

1. Query all student from the database
2. Then query result of above students using "IN" operator like `SELECT marks FROM result WHERE student_id IN (23,34,23,343,25,67,65,...)`
3. Then using foreach statement, process the result as required.
4. This way, it we have 100 students, we need to query the database just 2 times.

I need to know which of the above two cases is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from students join marks on students.student_id = marks.student_id
```

This should do it. And ofcourse the second option of yours seems to be better.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be:

```
SELECT marks FROM result JOIN students ON students.student_id = result.student_id;
```

[`join reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Yes this is also an option but the way I structured my tables and the way, I am displaying the data do not work with JOIN.